# Smoothing the Markov inequality Proof

Tags: statistics, inequality, proof-writing

I tried to prove the Lemma 5 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.06361.pdf (by Huber, 2019) but cannot figure out what's the best solution to tackle this smoothing Markov's inequality. Can anyone help me with the proof? Thank you.

> Lemma 5: For integrable $X$, $a \ge 0$, and $U$ a random variable independent
> of $X$ that is uniform over $[−a, a]$, $P(X+U \geq a) \leq \frac{E[X]}{2a}$

[Smoothing Markov's inequality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbYVA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a direct consequence of Lemma 4 on the same page. By said lemma applied to some nonnegative and integrable $X$ and $U\sim\mathrm{Unif}([-a,a])$, you have that
$$\mathbb P(X+U\ge a) = \mathbb E\left[f_1(X)\right]$$
Where
$$f_1(X):= \mathbf 1(X\ge 2a)+\frac{X}{2a}\mathbf 1(0\le X\le 2a)$$
Now, notice that the union of the two events $E_1:=\{X\ge2a\}$ and $E_2:=\{0\le X\le 2a\}$ has probability one, hence if we can bound $f_1(X)$ on each of these sets we get an almost sure bound for $f_1(X)$.

- For $\omega\in E_1$, we have $X(\omega)\ge2a\implies X(\omega)/2a \ge 1$. From this observation it follows that $f_1(X)(\omega)\le X(\omega)/2a$ for all $\omega \in E_1$.
- For $\omega\in E_2$, you have $f_1(X)(\omega) = X(\omega)/2a$ and thus $f_1(X)(\omega)\le X(\omega)/2a$ for all $\omega \in E_2$ as well.

We have just shown that $f_1(X)\le X/2a $ almost surely, hence, by monotonicity of $\mathbb E[\cdot]$ we have that
$$\mathbb P(X+U\ge a) = \mathbb E\left[f_1(X)\right]\le \mathbb E\left[\frac{X}{2a}\right]=\frac{\mathbb E[X]}{2a}$$

---

**Remark :** I implicitly assumed in all this that $E_3 = \{X=2a\}$ has measure zero, but if it is not the case the result still holds true since
$$\mathbb P(X+U\ge a\ |\ X=2a) = \mathbb P(2a+U\ge a) = 1 = X(\omega)/2a $$